# Persist a List with order and duplicates in JPA/EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, collections, persistence, eclipselink

I have basically two Entities `Entity1` and `Entity2`. 
`Entity1` contains this bit of Code:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@OrderColumn
List<Entity2> e = new LinkedList<Entity2>();
```

and `Entity2` contains some stuff, but nothing relevant. I want to add some instances to the list `e`, and most importantly i want to add some duplicates (the same reference) twice or more to the list. Still i want JPA to persist both and i want JPA to persist the Order of the list.

So far this works, if i add only unique items. If i add a duplicate, JPA actually wants to persist the correct data (ID od Entity1, ID of Entity2 and the order) but since the Primary key of the relationship table is only the two IDs, JPA throws an duplicate primary key error.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Who creates the DDL? It should contain a primary key definition with the order column and entity2 id column, not e1 id and e2 id. Hibernate's auto DDL creates a working definition.

Comment: eclipselink does that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink does not currently support duplicates for OneToMany relationships.  Duplicate are support for (basic) ElementCollection mappings.

Please vote for bug,
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=256978

The best solution is to map the join table to another entity and define a 1-m to it with a 1-1 to the target.