# Eclipselink JPA - Update entity with @EmbeddedCollection and map does not insert new entry

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I am looking at a very simple entity with a `Map` `@ElementCollection`.

The entity:

```
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @Data
public class Attribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Integer, AttributeValue> attributes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

The `Embeddable` used as the map value:

```
@Embeddable
@RequiredArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE) @Data
public class AttributeValue {

    @NonNull
    private String name;
}
```

When I try to update the entity with a new map entry where there is already an equal persisted value (with the same `name` in this case) the map entry is not inserted.

This test reproduces this issue:

```
@Test
    public void should_persist_attribute_with_same_value() {
        Attribute name = new Attribute("name");

        name.getAttributes().put(1, new AttributeValue("1"));
        name.getAttributes().put(2, new AttributeValue("2"));

        name = attributeRepository.saveAndFlush(name);

        name.getAttributes().put(3, new AttributeValue("2")); //this value is already in the map and is not inserted
        name.getAttributes().put(4, new AttributeValue("4"));

        name = attributeRepository.saveAndFlush(name);

        entityManager.clear();
        //the assertion fails and finds only three items (with key 1,2 and 4)
        then(attributeRepository.findOne(name.getId()).getAttributes()).hasSize(4);
    }
```

It seems that there is a bug in eclipselink that ignores map values that are already used with another map key in the map.

I also tried with hibernate - there the same code works as expected.

Any ideas?

I am using:

- spring-boot 1-4-0.M2
- spring-data-jpa 1.10.1.RELEASE
- eclipselink 2.6.1

Comment: EclipseLink does not support duplicates in collection mappings, though it does support it in basic ElementCollection mappings.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690347/persist-a-list-with-order-and-duplicates-in-jpa-eclipselink

Comment: @Chris this applies to maps as well? No duplicate values in Lists and Maps?